# Grabbing all <a> tags in a specific div and displaying them

Tags: jquery, html, image, attr

So I'v got a small problem with my portfolio site (you can see it at [here](http://www.taylorswyter.com/testing))

When you click on a portfolio piece, a top section opens up to reveal the details (Title, year, role, description) as well as the photos. I'v been able to get each project to replace all the text data, but I can't seem to get the images to load into the thumbnails.

I have been able to get the last image i'm looking for in all of the images on the site, but not display each photo for each project.

**Here's the HTML i'm working with:**

```
<section id="details">
    <div class="pagewrapper">
        <section id="main-img">
            <article id="big-img">
                <img src="" alt="big-img" />
            </article>



            <article class="small-img-container">
                <a href="#"><img src="#" alt="smallimg" class="small-img" /></a>
            </article>
        </section>

        <section id="description">
            <h3></h3>
            <h4></h4>
            <h5></h5>
            <p></p>
        </section>
    </div>

    <div class="clear"></div>

    </section>



    <section id="portfolio">
        <div class="pagewrapper">
            <h2 class="sectionTitle">Portfolio</h2>

            <div class="thumb">
                <a class="small" href="#" title="David Lockwood Music" data-year="2010" data-role="Sole Wordpress Developer" data-description="David Lockwood is a musician and an educator based in New Hampshire who came to me needing a website for his musical career. I fully developed his site using Wordpress as a CMS, creating a custom template based on the design by Jeremiah Louf. Jeremiah and I worked together on the website's UX design."><img src="images_original/davidcover.png" alt="thumb" />

                    <div class="hide">                      
                        <a href="images/davidlockwood/homepage.png" ></a>
                        <a href="images/davidlockwood/blog.png"></a>
                        <a href="images/davidlockwood/shows.png"></a>
                        <a href="images/davidlockwood/bio.png"></a>
                        <a href="images/davidlockwood/photos.png"></a>

                    </div>

                    <h3>David Lockwood Music</h3>
                    <div class="clear"></div>
                </a>
            </div><!--thumb-->
```

**and here's the jQuery:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var proj = {};

    $('.thumb a').click(function() {
        $('#details').slideDown(1000);



        $('.hide a').each(function() {
            proj.img = $(this).attr("href");
            $('.small-img-container img').attr('src',proj.img);

        });

        alert("the image is " + proj.img);//is it getting the image URLS?
        proj.title = $(this).attr("title");
        proj.year = $(this).attr("data-year");
        proj.role = $(this).attr("data-role");
        proj.description = $(this).attr("data-description");



        $('#description h3').text(proj.title);
        $('#description h4').text(proj.year);
        $('#description h5').text(proj.role);
        $('#description p').text(proj.description);

    });

});
```

Anyone have any idea how I grab just the images for the specific project, display them all as thumbnails and then make those thumbnail clickable to see the bigger image?

Thanks!

Comment: <a> tag shouldn't wrap any block element such as div ... Plus, you nested <a> tags in another <a> which might lead to unpredictable behaviour from browsers ...

Comment: "data-XXX" like attribute should be accessed with the data method like : `$node.data('year')`[see documentation](http://api.jquery.com/data/#data-html5)

Comment: Fixed both of those issues. Thanks for that!

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.hide a').each(function() {
    proj.img = $(this).attr("href");
    $('.small-img-container img').attr('src',proj.img);

});
```

`proj.img` will always get the value of the last image since youre iterating through all of the `a` tags

If i understand you correctly, this is what you need:

```
$('.thumb a').click(function() {

    var imageSrc = $(this).find('img[alt="thumb"]').attr('src');

    $('#big-img > img').attr({ src: imageSrc });

    var $thumbs = $(this).next('div.hide').find('img');

    $.each($thumbs, function(i, img){

        var $thumb = $(img)
            .click(function(){
                 $('#big-img > img').attr({ src: $(img).attr('src') });
             })
             .appendTo('#small-img-container');            


    });

});
```

Comment: so now that I have them in the array, and I can see that they're there with an alert, how do I get them out of the array and into a list of thumbnails? 

I'v tried looping through the array with a for loop but it still doesn't seem to work.

    var i;
    for(i = 0;i < smallImages.length; ++i) {
        $('small-img-container img').attr('src',smallImages[i]);
    }

Comment: Now I'm really confused. I'm not entirely sure what the new code is doing here. I see that it's finding an img tag then changing the src of that img tag to the href in the a tag and then appending it to the body (or in my case '.small-img-container img').

This sounds right, but it's still not working. When I put an alert in the if statement, it never comes up on the page. Is there maybe a better way to go about this whole process?

Comment: @TaylorSwyter Its not finding an img tag. Its generating a new img tag for each a-tag that has a href in the div tag with class hide next to the image which is clicked. If you still havent got what you need please elaborate and ill try to help

Comment: So basically, if you look at the page I have a list of projects made up of an image of the project and the title that is in an a-tag. Each project has a couple of images I want to show for them. When you click a project the detail section slides down and displays the detail information for the project as well as a small photo gallery with thumbnails. I'v got the text working fine, now it's just a matter of the photos. Once i'v got the list of photos displaying I just need each of them to reveal a larger image when clicked. I swear I'm so close to figuring this out.

Comment: @TaylorSwyter By larger image do you mean a lightbox or something similar?

Comment: I was thinking of just displaying it on the page instead of in a lightbox. If you look at www.taylorswyter.com/testing and click one of the projects, you'll see what I mean. (Also, i'm gonna make that image larger, the css isn't final right now.)

Comment: So, after playing with that new code a bit and discovering that if I make the <a>tags in '.hide' into <img>tags with alt="thumb" I can pull the first image into the big-img area. However, now I need to pull them all into that area so I can create the thumbnails that can be clicked-through. I'm getting only the first one right now. I think there should probably be an '.each()' somewhere in there, but i'm not quite sure where... Damn, so close to getting this figured out.

Comment: So, this gets the first image with an alt="thumb" from the list and displays it in the #big-img. If I can get them all to display there I could do what I'm trying to do, but right now it's only the first one that shows up in #big-img.

Comment: ^^ Sorry, forgot to tag you in this.

Answer (score 0):

So, I rewrote everything, but I think this would make it easier.

Working with data-attributes and just building everything from there on. My solution requires that you work with down-scaled images (through CSS) which you display in full after click.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BramVanroy/7Wp9z/1/).

jQuery:

```
$("div#links > a").click(function(e) {
    var ID = $(this).data("content");
    var price = $(this).data("price");
    var descr = $(this).data("description");
    var rating = $(this).data("rating");

    $("div#images > img").hide();
    $("span#price, span#description, span#rating").text("").hide();

    $("div#images").children("img#" + ID).fadeToggle("slow");
    $("div#text span#price").text(price);
    $("div#text span#description").text(descr);
    $("div#text span#rating").text(rating);
    $("span#price, span#description, span#rating").fadeIn("fast");
    $("div#text").fadeIn("fast");

    e.preventDefault();
});

$("div#images > img").click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("active");
    var marginL = -$(this).width() / 2;
    $("div#images > img.active").css("margin-left", marginL);
    $("div#images > img:not(.active)").css("margin-left", "0px");

    if ($("div#overlay").is(":hidden")) {
        $("div#overlay").fadeIn("fast");
    }
    else {
        $("div#overlay").fadeOut("fast");
    }
});​
```